# Install hadoop before installing Spark

Tags: python3, hadoop, jupyter-notebook

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server on virtualbox. My goal is to achieve the following.

1. Install Hadoop and Spark;
2. Run Spark on top of Hadoop using its hdfs as storage;
3. Install Jupyter and develop/run Scala and Pyspark.

Hadoop would be running as a single node. My Questions are

1. Do i first install Hadoop, configure it and then install Spark?
2. How do i install and run Jupyter with Scala kernel to run applications using Spark and Hadoop?

Any response and/or pointers towards walkthroughs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's Spark "on top of Hadoop", so yes you should start with Hadoop (HDFS/YARN), and when you have a working cluster (the distributedshell is a good test utility), you can install Spark.
You only need spark on edge nodes (user's machines), but since it's a single node cluster I guess everything will run side by side.
The configuration is even simpler this way as all hadoop dependancies and environmenet variables should already be set properly.

You can specify which python executable pyspark (spark python module) should use. It can be jupyter easily:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Then, launching "pyspark" should open a notebook which will be your Spark Driver.

I'm experiencing with Hadoop 3 so as a piece of advice, if you wish to use GPUs, better stick to Hadoop 2.9.xx for now. Spark was not tested that much under Hadoop 3.x so it's a mess to have things up and running.